# How to replace multiple characters of UITextView text in real time with Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview

Here are my codes:

```
func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {
        if let newCharacters = newTextView.text?.enumerated() {
            for (index, item) in newCharacters {
                switch item {
                    case “1”:
                        newText.text = newTextView.text?.replacingOccurrences(of: “1”, with: “1⃣️”)
                    case “2”:
                        newText.text = newTextView.text?.replacingOccurrences(of: “2”, with: “2⃣️”)
                    case “3”:
                        newText.text = newTextView.text?.replacingOccurrences(of: “3”, with: “3⃣️”)
                default: break
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Here is how it looks like:

[image]

But I would like to replace all the characters of the UITextView in real time, not only the last character of the text. Any ideas or suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: You should research UITextFieldDelegate and its functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error occurs because by replacing the last character with your emoji, you are returning the previous text to the textview.

Create a variable where you store the emoji numbers and at the end, replace the text of your textview with the text of your variable.

```
   func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {
    if let newCharacters = newTextView.text?.enumerated() {
        var newText = newTextView.text
        for (index, item) in newCharacters {
            switch item {
            case “1”:
                newText?.replacingOccurrences(of: “1”, with: “1⃣️”)
            case “2”:
                newText?.replacingOccurrences(of: “2”, with: “2⃣️”)
            case “3”:
                newText?.replacingOccurrences(of: “3”, with: “3⃣️”)
            default: break
            }
        }
        newTextView.text = newText
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh, Rey, you are the genius. Thank you very much.